# Debug beeping in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa

Sometimes when I press the backspace key, my app... beeps.

Since this beep is not caused by my code (I removed all calls to `NSBeep`), I suspect the cause is that there is an object responding the the backspace key that shouldn't be.

How can I debug the source of the beep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way! By adding a Symbolic Breakpoint of `NSBeep` I managed to find the offending responder.